# Using DateTime to check bookings in the current week

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a method that checks how many bookings I have in the current month:

`if (item.DateTimeScheduled.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)`

Is it possible to do something similar for the current week? How can I check the number of bookings done in the current week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a collection of "Items" with a `DateTime` property and you want to count all of this week, this should work:

```
var calendar = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
var weekRule = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CalendarWeekRule;
var firstDay = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek;
int week = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Today, weekRule, firstDay);
int thisWeekBookings = items
    .Count(i => i.DateTimeScheduled.Year == DateTime.Today.Year &&
        week == calendar.GetWeekOfYear(i.DateTimeScheduled, weekRule, firstDay));
```